# How many words can be written with using the letters ELLHELY so that 3 L's are never in a row and no E's are ever next to each other?

Tags: combinatorics

My approach was as follows:

1: Find the number of total different words that can be made. Did this by $\frac{7!}{3!2!}$ since three L's repeat and two E's repeat. Answer: 420.

2: Find the number of cases where all three L's are in a row. Did this by $\frac{5!}{2!}$ where I treat the three L's as one item, thus 7 becomes 5 and only the 2 from the repeating E's is left on the bottom. Answer: 60.

3: Find the number of cases where two E's are next to each other. I treat the E's as one item and use $\frac{6!}{3!}$ to find this where the 3 on the bottom represents the repeating L's. Answer: 120.

4: I subtract the amount of "invalid" cases which we found in 2 and 3 from the total that we found in 1. So 420 - 30 - 20 = 370. Answer 370 ways.

I know this would be correct if these were separate questions, so is it still correct when I apply both of them (step 4)?

Thank you!

Edit: Counted the factorials wrong, fixed now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot something: You substracted the words, where both conditions (the one on the $\sf L$s and the one on the $\sf E$s) are met, twice. So you have to add them again, once. There are $4!$ of them (we just treat the $\sf L$s and the $\sf E$s as one letter each), so alltogether we have
$$ \frac{7!}{3!2!} - \frac{5!}{2!} - \frac{6!}{3!} + 4! 
  = 420 - {\color{red}{60}} - {\color{red}{120}} + 24 = 264 $$

Comment: Won't this mean that we only add the cases where all five letters are in a row (LLLEE)? What about  cases where they are spread like LLLHYEE?

Comment: No, we treat $\sf LLL$ and $\sf EE$ each as one letter, so spread cases are included.

Comment: I got it! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Use *inclusion/exclusion principle*:

- Include the total number of words: $\binom73\cdot\binom42\cdot\binom21\cdot\binom11=420$
- Exclude the number of words with LLL: $\binom51\cdot\binom42\cdot\binom21\cdot\binom11=60$
- Exclude the number of words with EE: $\binom63\cdot\binom31\cdot\binom21\cdot\binom11=120$
- Include the number of words with LLL and EE: $\binom41\cdot\binom31\cdot\binom21\cdot\binom11=24$

So the number of words without LLL or EE is $420-60-120+24=264$.

Comment: I chose to accept martini's answer because it had a more specific explanation, but once I understood what I was doing wrong your answer made a lot of sense.  Thank you!

Comment: @constantlyconfused: You're welcome :)